# Unit test for request retry function

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a request retry function that sends post requests 3 times per session and if the post request does not give the response back after 3 attempts then it will raise an error. The function is as follows:

```
def request_retry_session():

     session = requests.Session()
     retry = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.1, 
     method_whitelist=frozenset(['POST']))
     adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
     session.mount('http://', adapter)
     try:
            response = session.post(
                url=url,
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                verify=False,
            )
            response_data = response.json()  
            logger.info(f"{ref}processing time cost for {api_name}: {time_cost}s")
      except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

I would like to write unit test for this function. I would appreciate it if you have any advice.

Comment: What do you want to validate that the function does?  I.e. what sort of breakage do you want to prevent someone else (or someone else) from introducing in the future?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but catching and re-raising `Exception` is pointless -- just remove the `try/except` block entirely, it'll do the same thing (since uncaught exceptions raise automatically).  The only reason to explicitly `raise` in a an `except` block is if you want to do something else related to the exception (e.g. logging or recovery) before raising.

Comment: @Samwise I am trying to check if the function is working or not in the unit test

Comment: What does "working" mean in this context?  The functionality you describe is implemented in the `Retry` object, not in this function, so it's not clear what there is for you to unit test.

Comment: In the unit test, I would like to check how many times did the retry function tried to create a new session before failing. In this case, it should be 3

Comment: That should be covered by the unit tests for `HTTPAdapter` and `Retry`.  Do you have the source code for those classes?